# Calling Python self made package from any directories

Tags: python, module, package

I have the following directory structures:

```
mydir/
   MyTask1/
      job1.py
      MyPackage/
         __init__.py
        cool_code.py
      MyTask1_1/
        job2.py
    MyTask3/
       job3.py
```

The package which I create is called `MyPackage`, the `__init__.py` only contain a docstring. 
What I want to do is from `job2.py` and `job3.py`, I can call the module the following way

```
# job2.py or job3.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from MyPackage import cool_code
```

What should I modify and add to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

you can modify sys.path to extend the module search path, eg.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/mydir/MyTask1')
from MyPackage import cool_code
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can modify `__init__.py` in `MyPackage` so that I don't have to do sys.path.insert() in every `job*.py` codes?

Comment: chicken-egg...  if with the current setup job2 and job3 don't see MyPackage, the __init__ file will not be loaded, so no change in that file will make it visible in different directories. but you could change the PYTHONPATH environment variable in your system in order to make this package visible to all python scripts

Answer (score 0):

From job2.py:

```
PROJ_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
if not PROJ_ROOT in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(PROJ_ROOT)
from mydir.MyTask1.MyPackage import cool_code
```

From job3.py:

```
PROJ_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
if not PROJ_ROOT in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(PROJ_ROOT)
from mydir.MyTask3 import cool_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your module path relative to `__init__.py` and define module structure. You can find example here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

If you want to load while:

```
from MyPackage import cool_code
```

You can use `__all__` in `__init__.py` as defined here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: `You could define your module path relative to __init__.py` can you give specific example to address my question above?

Comment: There is an example at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages. I gave the link...